# Facebook Wall Post

Tags: facebook

I have created one Web Application in ASP.Net. In That am able to connect with FaceBook and getting data from logged in user's profile. now i would like to post a message on wall. i have found the STREAM.PUBLISH method but i dont know how to use it. it asks me for permission. so is there any other way to post message on wall, any exmple using ASP.Net

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here you can find a tutorial about it:

> http://www.barattalo.it/2010/01/17/posting-to-facebook-from-website-with-facebook-connect/

Since it's written in php you have to translate something, but the important job is made with the facebook javascript api.